# Can`t load a webpage using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

Good day.

Ive performed the following Selenium test and them Exported its code in Python. It works fine on Selenium IDE but for some reason its Python counterpart doesnt load the pages, it simply open Firefox with a blank page.

I'm using Python 2.7, I'm o window 7 and my Firefox version is 49.0.1.

Here is the very begging of the code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time, re

class CasoDeTesteStiMEmPython(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "some webpage"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_caso_de_teste_sti_m_em_python(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("the webpage i need it to go")
        driver.find_element_by_name("USER").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("USER").send_keys("my login")
        driver.find_element_by_name("PASSWORD").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("PASSWORD").send_keys("my password")
```

Comment: This should work, as long as the `self.base_url` is set properly, and `driver.get()` is set properly. `driver.get("https://www.google.com")` works for all Selenium webdrivers.

Comment: Is there any exception??

Comment: Make sure the url includes the "http://" prefix.

Comment: it didnt really work, it still only opens a blank page.

Comment: Firefox version >=49 needs Geckodriver to be present.  do you have that on your path?

Comment: Probably not, ill check this out

Comment: sorry, i mispoke - it's versions >=48 that needs geckodriver

Comment: Well, then i guess i might have to use geckodriver, all the tutorials ive found use JAva, do you have any that uses python as an example?